# Css 3 Pie on localhost

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, localhost, css3pie

I'm using MAMP on OS X and native IE7 for testing on Parallels. I'm developing an intranet website that will run on a local server. The browser all the employees have installed is IE7, so I need to use Css3Pie for some stuff, like rounded corners and shadows.

I have tried all the following:

- `behavior: url(PIE.htc);` (relative to the html file and added the mime in .htaccess)
- `behavior: url(absoluteurl/PIE.php);`

Neither method is working for me. I have tried all the possible combinations, but it doesn't work. Do you know if there are any issues testing/running it on a localhost?

Comment: If your entire target audience is IE7, I would reccomend simply doing things the old fashioned way with images.

Comment: bookcasey, I agree with you, I just wanted to use some css, so if they upgrade their browsers, I can remove the css3pie and the website would be ready as is. But yes, I'm thinking about going with images.

Comment: I'm using it on localhost right now and it works fine. So it is possible.

Comment: related? http://stackoverflow.com/a/19376600/759452

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There shouldn't be any problem with using it on localhost. It's possible Parallels is getting in the way somehow, but I doubt it. **Most likely it's due to incorrect installation**. Even though I've installed PIE several times, it always takes some troubleshooting to get it running.

Some debugging tips:

- Try calling the the pie url from firefox or chrome and check the network traffic with developer tools/firebug.
- Confirm you're not getting a 404.
- Confirm the server is returning the file with the correct content-type header.
- I've heard [others recommending using Fiddler](http://css3pie.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=1200) for the above steps -- not sure if that will work with your Parallels setup.

Comment: Thanks, I gave up with PIE a and switched to http://fetchak.com/ie-css3/ that worked ok for my little needs.