# CSS3PIE Not Working With border-radius

Tags: html, css, css3pie

I am trying to get CSS3PIE to work for my site so I can use border-radius in IE8 (and earlier). It works fine in all other browsers. Here's my CSS:

```
#body_text_design{
    border:2px solid black;
    background-color:#CCC;
    background-image:url(../pics/designbg.png);
    font-family:"Britannic Bold";
    color:black;
    height:676px;
    width:675px;
    -webkit-border-radius:10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-top:23px;
    overflow:hidden;
    behavior: url(PIE.htc);
    }
```

And my HTML:

```
<div id="body_box">
    <div id="body_text_design">

    <div class="design_text_div">
    <h1>Test test test</h1>
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <h3>Bla bla bla</h3> 
    <h3>Test test test</h3>
    </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

I have tried all the debugging that I could find such as:

- tried the PHP solution
- tried a full http:// link to the PIE.htc file
- added `AddType text/x-component .htc` to my .htaccess file
- tried `position:absolute` and `zoom:1` and z-index values.

Nothing has worked so far. I envy those that have gotten this just by adding the `behavior` property to their CSS. If anybody could help, that would be greatly appreciated!

### EDIT

Here's a jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/3aWVH/1/

Comment: can you create an example for better understanding

Comment: your code works for me. Make sure the path to your htc file is correct. i tested it on my local pc tho. eg path: C:\Users\...\test.html Not sure if it is a issue of your server setting or sth

Comment: Yeah I've had the PIE.htc in the right location. I even actually put it in multiple folders just to make sure it was in the right place somewhere and it didn't work. I'm having trouble testing it on my local PC because all I have is a Mac right now and IE8 isn't available for Mac. The only other thing I can think is that it has something to with GoDaddy (they host the site I'm designing). I've Googled but can't find any hard facts that there are permission issues with htc files with GoDaddy. Any ideas on that?

Comment: Can you try placing the behavior style immediately after the border radius definitions and see if that helps?

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you are not testing locally. .htc files needs to be hosted on server and css3 pie will work only in web container

Comment: This. Kind of a weird issue to have, but testing it on my publically accessible staging environment did the trick.

Comment: @Pranay Krondekar: thx for the tip, this is the kind of information that should be displayed on CSS3PIE official website & documentation

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with this problem for awhile and finally figured it out!

Some servers don't recognize the .htc file so you have to add the Content-type to your .htaccess file by putting this:

```
AddType text/x-component .htc
```

It's on the known issues page of the documentation http://css3pie.com/documentation/known-issues/

Comment: oh sorry, I missed where you said that in your question :/ sorry

Answer (score 0):

I have access to the `.htaccess` but it made no difference adding `AddType text/x-component .htc`, however using the `PIE.php` did work (although I had been using a mistyped path at first so took me 3 days to work out that the `php` really did work all along!)... anyway, all looking good now!